# Can Docker Compose build a ZooKeeper discovery service for Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Found this [Five Server Docker Example](https://github.com/lukeolbrish/examples/tree/master/zookeeper/five-server-docker) . It uses Docker Compose to deploy a 5 host ensemble.

My questions are:

1. Can that ZooKeeper instance subsequently be used as a Discovery Service in Swarm? If so, how would that be accomplished (assuming there was a unique host for each of the five ZK nodes and those would form the entirety of the swarm)?
2. Related to the first question - the Docker Documentation says that "Compose and Swarm aim to have full integration... meaning you can point a Compose app at a Swarm Cluster".  What I have read seems to presuppose the Cluster already exists.  So I am wondering: how much of the Swarm Cluster can Compose compose? That is, is it possible to have Compose also build the swarm cluster it will subsequently use?

Relatively new to Docker (if you can't already tell!), so if you can answer either question in such a way that minimizes assumptions about what is known, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

To the first question: Yes you could do that but the you need some kind of discovery service (or loadbalancer) for your zookeepers.

To the second Question: no you can't. You need a dicovery Backend present before initialize a swam and you cannot deploy the discovery backend to the Swarm before this swarm exists. This is a Chicken Egg Problem

Better wait some time until the Swarm Mode of Docker 1.12 has gained a little bit maturity